# Windows Service Freezes on ExecuteReader from DB c#

Tags: c#, oracle

I have a Windows service, installed on a server. However, we noticed that at some point it stops working, even though, it still shows as running on the server.
After investigations, we noticed that it freezes, when command.ExecuteReader is called. But this happens intermittently. At other times, it works perfectly. See code snapshot below

```cs
using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(Section["ConnectionString"].ToString()))
{
    IDbCommand command = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
    command.CommandText = query;
    command.Connection = connection;

    IDataReader dataReader = null;

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        LogToFile("Connected");

        dataReader = command.ExecuteReader(); //INTERMITENTLY FREEZES HERE
        LogToFile("ExecuteReader completed");
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            TransactionFromFinacle item = new TransactionFromFinacle
            {
                AccountNo = dataReader["AccountNo"].ToString(),
                ...
            };

            result.Add(item);
        }
        log.Debug("Finished reading"));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogToFile(ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (dataReader != null)
        {
            if (!dataReader.IsClosed)
            {
                dataReader.Dispose();
            }
        }
        
        if (connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
           command.Cancel();
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

What could be the issue with this?

Comment: You should define _freeze_. Do you have a stack from a dump when this happens?

Comment: Nothing.  When you have a large database results may not come back at a constant rate.  The datareader implements ienumerator which waits for next result which may occur immediately or after a period or time.

Comment: Analyse `query`. My first bet would be, it just takes ages.

Comment: Look to see if the query is running inside Oracle and if it is blocked due to a database lock or whatever.  If you have a DBA, they should be able to help you.  If you have sufficient rights you can check for yourself using a technique like shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46474920/oracle-report-with-long-running-sql

Comment: @Fildor _Smells like teen spirit_. I mean... db locks. Optimizing the query would be my second guess

Comment: @Flydog57, by Freeze, I mean processing would stop, and things would not go beyond that line of code. You can wait till tomorrow, nothing will work. Also the service is supposed to run repeatedly every hour - this would also stop. But the service would still be showing in running state. No logs, that's the funny thing

Comment: @Fildor, the query typically takes about 3+ mins to run normally (when it does not freeze).

Comment: @ajz, yes, I would need to look into locks. thanks.

Comment: @osagie That's already quite long ... So, if you can rule out locks, you may want to look into if there are combinations of paramters to the query that makes it perform even worse than your average 3 minutes.

Comment: @Cleptus Actually my personal plan would be to look at the query for _obvious_ mishaps, then locks, then deeper analysis of query.